# Set text in multiple text boxes in cells in a grid in C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

I'm new to C# and have set up a grid with 4 rows and 7 columns with a text box in each cell. I know how to manipulate the text boxes, but how can I iterate through the cells to access each text box?

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (TextBox tb in theGrid.Children) tb.Text = "the text";
```